# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^2}\leq2-\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

> I am asked to prove by induction that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^2}\leq2-\frac{1}{n}$$

The base case is straightforward: $$\sum_{i=1}^{1}\frac{1}{1^2}\leq2-\frac{1}{1}$$

However, for the inductive step, the solution states that $n^2+2n \leq n^2 + 2n + 1$ or $(n+1)n + n \leq (n+1)^2$. This becomes $2 - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \leq 2 - \frac{1}{n+1}$.

"From this, we can use the inductive hypothesis to see $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{i^2}\leq + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \leq 2-\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \leq 2 - \frac{1}{n+1}"$$

Can you explain how we can come up with a quadratic equation on the right hand side and how that relates to the solution?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Noticed i was missing dollar signs :) Edited.

Comment: I don't see any quadratic equation in that explanation.

Comment: @Alejandro Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bi%5E2%7D%20%5Cle%202%20-%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%24&p=1), a question which basically has your procedure in reverse, i.e., going from $2 - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \leq 2 - \frac{1}{n+1}$ to $n^2+2n \leq n^2 + 2n + 1$, is [Is $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{1}{k^2} \leq 2 -\frac{1}{n}$ correctly proved by induction?](/q/3627641). ...

Comment: @Alejandro (cont.)  Other dup. questions are [How does $\frac{-1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \leq \frac{-1}{k+1}$ helps to show that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\frac1{i^2}\leq \ 2-\frac{1}{k}$](/q/2009863), [Standard Problem on Mathematical-Induction](/q/2575501), [Proof by induction involving inequalities and summation.](/q/3440759), [Prove that for $ \displaystyle n≥1, \sum_ {i=1} ^{ n} \dfrac 1 {i^2} ≤ 2 - \dfrac 1 n$](/q/924445), [Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} \le 2 - \frac{1}{n}$](/q/638418), [Prove that for every positive integer $n$, $1/1^2+1/2^2+1/3^2+\cdots+1/n^2\le2-1/n$](/q/351166) ...

Comment: @Alejandro (cont.) and, finally, the first part of [Prove summation inequality with induction](/q/1974167).